# how to access multiple UITextView in table view cells

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a table view with several cells, each containing a UITextView.
The user can edit each text view that he clicks.
But when he clicks DONE, how do I access each text view, to read each that was edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UItextField delegate to get the text from current text filed as -

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *textFieldValue = [textField text];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your UITextView is called "tv"
You can use something like:

```
NSString *contents = tv.text;
```

I believe you can also use something along the lines of:

```
NSString *contents = [tv getText];
```